# Make all pages on domain go through specific page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to get all pages on the domain, like on the domain example.com to go through a index.php without editing the url.  I can use htaccess and php.  For example, on the domain example.com I can go to example.com/thefile.php and it will still show the main file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using the .htaccess for NamelessMC. The .htaccess file is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```